# Boost condition_variable destruction assert

Tags: c++, boost, synchronization, boost-thread

My question is: is there something specific I need to do (like call notify_all?) in the destructor of a thread that encapsulates a boost::condition_variable. The following code generates this assert when the Test destructor is called:

> cond_var:
>   /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/condition_variable_fwd.hpp:38:
>   boost::condition_variable::~condition_variable(): Assertion
>   `!pthread_cond_destroy(&cond)' failed. Aborted

```
#include <boost/thread/mutex.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/condition_variable.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

class Test {
public:

    ~Test() { /* ??? */ }

    int getI() {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(mtx);
        cond_var.wait(lock);
        return i;
    }

    void putI() {
        i=10;
        cond_var.notify_one();
    }

    int i;

    boost::mutex mtx;
    boost::condition_variable cond_var;
} t;

void runPut () {
    for(;;) {
        t.getI();
    }
}

void runGet () {
    for(;;) {
        t.putI();
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(100));
    }
}

int main() {
    boost::thread t1(&runPut);
    boost::thread t2(&runGet);

    boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
    return 0;
}
```

(gdb) bt

```
0  0x00007ffff70c4d05 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
1  0x00007ffff70c8ab6 in abort () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
2  0x00007ffff70bd7c5 in __assert_fail () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
3  0x0000000000406a35 in boost::condition_variable::~condition_variable (this=0x6104d0,
__in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at /usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/condition
_variable_fwd.hpp:38
4  0x0000000000406f42 in Test::~Test (this=0x6104a0, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at cond_var.cpp:19
5  0x00007ffff70ca961 in exit () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
6  0x00007ffff70aff06 in __libc_start_main () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
7  0x0000000000405899 in _start ()
```

Comment: The platform is ubuntu linux 11.04 with boost-1.42, gcc 4.52

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the two threads you've created before you exit. Add a global boolean variable called say, 'stop', initialized to false, and have t1 and t2 check that it's false every iteration:

```
bool stop = false;

void runPut () {
    while( !stop ) {
        t.getI();
    }
}

void runGet () {
    while( !stop ) {
        t.putI();
        boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(100));
    }
}
```

Then after your sleep in main set it to true, and call join on t1 and t2.

```
boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
stop = true;
t1.join();
t2.join();
```

Otherwise the condition variables are getting destroyed while still in use.